# AS3: Getting the 3D middle position of a 3D triangle

Tags: actionscript-3, math, 3d

The middle point of a 3D triangle is the intersection of three segments that connect each vertex and the midpoint of its opposite side.

Say a 3D triangle is defined by three `Vector3D` instances. How do I get the middle point (in `Vector3D` form) using the same algorithm?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
diagonal1 = (1-t)*A + t*(B+C)/2
diagonal2 = (1-s)*B + s*(A+C)/2
intersection at t = s = 2/3
which gives point p = (A+B+C)/3
```